# Broswer bookmarks that move like real ones?

Tags: bookmarks, firefox-extensions

Suppose I'm reading War & Peace, online, with a browser.  I'd like to mark my progress with a bookmark.  Unfortunately a browser 'bookmark' can only be created and deleted, not *moved*.

Is there a solution for this?

[The same question could be asked for PDF files, but I'll save that for later.]

Comment: I think you should ask this question on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can edit a bookmark in Firefox, although delete/create might be easier.

1. Copy your current location
2. From the menu, choose `Bookmarks > Show All Bookmarks`
3. Find the bookmark you want to edit (easiest to use the search bar) and select it
4. Paste your current location in the location field
5. Close the window